# Document field values as a parameter for nested subqueries in solr

Tags: solr, subquery

I have the following nested data for solr:

```
<add>
  <doc>
  <field name="id">1</field>
  <field name="path">1.root</field>
  <field name="title_tsi">Solr has block join support</field>
  <field name="type">parentDocument</field>
    <doc>
      <field name="id">2</field>
      <field name="path">2.root.sub</field>
      <field name="parent">1</field>
      <field name="comments_tsi">SolrCloud supports it too!</field>
      <field name="type">childDocument</field>
      <field name="subcomment_tsi">
        <doc>
          <field name="id">5</field>
          <field name="path">3.root.sub.sub2</field>
          <field name="parent">2</field>
          <field name="comments_tsi">This is a subcomment</field>
          <field name="type">childchildDocument</field>
        </doc>
    </doc>
  </field>
  </doc>
</add>
```

I want to display that nested data as is with a solr query. As far as I can tell, this is not possible with the ChildDocTransformerFactory, since that will only yield all descendants of a document in a flattened hiearchy, regardless of which level (child, grandchild, etc.) they are.

However, this appears to be possible with subqueries. As is described [in the documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/transforming-result-documents.html#document-field-as-an-input-for-subquery-parameters), with a query like

```
q=path:1.*&fl=*,d1:[subquery]&d1.q={!terms f=parent v=$row.id}
```

will result in displaying all the root documents, followed by displaying all the child documents within the root documents.

However, if I want to extend this to also include the grandchild documents within the child documents, by adding a subquery to the subquery, my query will fail.

```
q=path:1.*&fl=*,d1:[subquery]&d1.q={!terms f=parent v=$row.id}&d1.fl=*,d2:[subquery]&d2.q={!terms f=parent v=$row.id}
```

This will yield ALL the grandchild documents for all the child documents, not just the ones where the corresponding id/parent entries should match.

So my questions are:

1) What does "$row.id" refer to in the query, exactly? I could not find documentation on the subject. In the first subquery it clearly refers to the original id of the root documents, as it should. But how do I make it refer to the id of the child document in the second subquery?

2) Is there a smarter way to go about this for nested data of depth n?